# POST Querystring using WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to execute a `QueryString` using WebClient but using the POST Method

That is what I got so far

CODE:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.QueryString.Add("somedata", "value");
    client.DownloadString("uri");
}
```

It is working but unfortunately it is using GET not POST and the reason I want it to use POST is that I am doing a web scraping and this is how the request is made as I see in WireShark. [IT USES POST AS A METHOD BUT NO POST DATA ONLY THE QUERY STRING.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your specific question:

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
byte[] response = client.UploadData("your url", "POST", new byte[] { });
//get the response as a string and do something with it...
string s = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
```

But using WebClient can be a PITA since it doesn't accept cookies nor allow you to set a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you, use `WebRequest` instead of `WebClient`.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
class ThreadTest
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.yourDomain.com/search");

        req.Proxy = null;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string reqString = "searchtextbox=webclient&searchmode=simple"; 
        byte[] reqData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString); 
        req.ContentLength = reqData.Length;

        using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
            reqStream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);

        using (WebResponse res = req.GetResponse())
        using (Stream resSteam = res.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resSteam)) 
            File.WriteAllText("SearchResults.html", sr.ReadToEnd());

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SearchResults.html");

    }

}
```